# When I do the SetParent() my child goes far aways from the parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an object child of the Player, to follow the Player moves, and I don't want my child so far from the parent, but not too close, and when I make that object child of the Player it goes far away from the Player but in the Transform it looks like have similar coordenates. This happens because the object that I want be the child have an animation on y axis.

About the code, I have an `OnColiisionEnter` method that increase a variable `order` and then:

```
if(order == 2)
{
    Object1.transform.SetParent(playerLocation); //playerLocation already is a Transform
}
```

Simple as that. But with a little discussion I get that the problem is because of an animation that the values always changing so I don't thing it is a code problem.

I will leave a video here just to see what is happening: [Video](https://youtu.be/epx_vJ54-PY)

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: There's not enough information to reproduce the problem. Please include enough of the code and configuration you're using to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If I post my own code it will be more confusing so Im trying to simplify the code, but I can say that I have a OnColissionEnter method that increase a variable order and have an if(order == 2) and then the SetParent line code.

Comment: Let me ask something: does disabling the animator make the problem disappear? If the animator is part of the problem, its configuration needs to be part of the question.  Currently, there is still not enough information to reproduce the problem, so I'm voting to put the question on hold.

Comment: Yes it does. Well I dont know how to show the configuration of the animation do you have an ideia to show it?

Comment: Yes it is, my bad, I had no ideia that the problem is because the animator. I already have a solution for it but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confirmed that the issue is actually caused by the Animator.

The issue is that as soon as there does any keyframe exist for a property in any AnimationClip then the Animator hold like a "block" on it and overwrites the value. In your case it seems to be an animated `localPosition` so the child always gets an offset to its parent.

The only solution for this I'm aware of would be to let the sphere object always have a parent object by default

```
Object1Parent
|-- Object1 (+Animator)
```

Then let your script not change the parent object of the sphere but instead of its parent so the local animations stay intact:

```
Player
|-- Object1Parent
    |-- Object1 (+Animator)
```

then in your script simply either reference the parent object instead or use

```
Object1.transform.parent.SetParent(playerLocation);
```

Comment: I did that and I just noticed that the sphere was disapearing and it is because in the animation the x and z value is always the same and make the object move. Maybe I need to do the animation again.

Comment: Ok its done. Thank you for your help, understand and wasted time. I appreciate it alot.